# How do I close a node.js live-server on Windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-live-server

I am new to node.js and following a course on the topic. I have already installed node and npm and now I have opened a live-server on a simple project and would like to know if there is some way to close it again.
I just put `live-server` into PowerShell to open the server and now I don't know how I am supposed to close it again. I know that if I just close the Terminal, the server shuts down but how can I close the server without having to close my Terminal?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ctrl + C is generally the input needed to cancel a running terminal command

Comment: Thank you! In the course the person was using a mac and I was wondering what the weird symbols infront of the 'C' were! This makes it so much easier!

Comment: Hi Daniel, if the user was using a Mac I suggest you update the reference to Windows in the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`ctrl + C` is usually used for this purpose. works for both Mac and windows.